# best way to do Flip animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two Bitmaps(Original & Flipped one). I want to use an animation to show flip. Which is the best way to go ahead about this?
Can i use a ImageSwitcher/Animator Object ?

Comment: You should use a flipper. Wanna know how its used?

Comment: flipper is fine, How do i gt the animation?

Comment: Is there a standard api in animation for flip? or do i need to write my own xml for translation

Answer (score 0):

there is this AWESOME link that I used when I had to do flip animations in my app a few months ago.

try it, it works:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Answer (score 0):

Here Another Good flip Example

http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/